# Renaming LWC const variable breaks component behavior

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, variable-names

I was surprised to find that changing the variable name for a JS `const` from `fields` to `CONTACT_FIELDS` caused my component to stop functioning. (I realize this is a naming convention for [Java constants](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/codeconventions-135099.html), but I was using in my LWC.)

Specifically, changing `fields` to `CONTACT_FIELDS` in the below code (no other references to this variable in the .js file) will no longer retrieve the wired Contact fields.

**Anyone know why??**

```
const fields = ['Contact.Name', 'Contact.Owner.Name', 'Contact.Owner.FirstName'];

export default class Transfer extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    ownedRecord;
```

Comment: With the way you have the `fields` should be written as `fields: fields` and changing it to `CONTACT_FIELDS` should be as `fields: CONTACT_FIELDS`. Is your current code snippet correct?

Comment: Oh, derp. You're totally right... adding the key fixes it with the new variable name. Yet SOMEHOW the code shown above (fields without key name) also works.  Maybe THAT's the (revised) question.  I had lazily copied from [a repo](https://github.com/ashish413/LWC_QuickAction/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/contactDetailsLWC/contactDetailsLWC.js) and didn't notice that this should be an object key/value pair.  Does JS auto-set key name if only one variable is provided for an object key/value entry?

Comment: I am not really sure how that worked if you didn't specify a value to `fields`, haven't come across it. Will try and then can explain better. But changing the variable name and being able to utilize that in the wire adapter, you'll need to pass it to the attribute.

Comment: @JayantDas The reason it worked as `@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })` is because [ES2015 allows shorthand notation for object literals](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand), where instead of writing `{ a: a, b: b, c: c }`, you can simply write `{ a, b, c }` (this assumes a, b, and c are defined variables - this is why chaning the name of `field` breaks it). So in this case, `@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })` is the same as `@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: fields })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the attribute `fields` to be passed correctly to the wire adapter [`getRecord()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record). The `fields` attribute expects a field name array. If you used a variable named `fields` to declare the array, then your code should be written as:

```
const fields = ['Contact.Name', 'Contact.Owner.Name', 'Contact.Owner.FirstName'];
...
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: fields })
```

If you rename the `fields` variable to `CONTACT_FIELDS` then you should update the reference in the adapter too:

```
const CONTACT_FIELDS = ['Contact.Name', 'Contact.Owner.Name', 'Contact.Owner.FirstName'];
...
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: CONTACT_FIELDS })
```

Comment: that is slightly inaccurate - the case where the variable is named fields is perfectly fine. That is a es6 shorthand - if the propertyname and fieldname are equal you can omit the value association and just write {field}. 
Just in case if the names are different (fields != CONTACT_FIELDS) you have to explicitly declare it (http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand)

Comment: Exactly this is wrong ! It should work with shorthand notation as well .You do not need key:value if value=key .